# Android: Item Click Listener in ListView which is Inside a Dialog

Tags: android

i have this code

```
private ListView event_list;
event_list = (ListView) open_event_list.findViewById(R.id.events_list);
loadList(cw.getDate());
```

"cw" is a CalendarView which is clicked, depending on what date u clicked a dialog box will appear containing the ListView... just see picture below
Inside loadList() method is

```
Cursor c = dbHelper.retrieveAllEventsWhere(TABLE_NAME, cwdate);
sched_list = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
Schedule s;
c.moveToFirst();
while(!c.isAfterLast())
{
    s = new Schedule();
    s.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    s.setTitle(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title")));
    s.setDescription(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("desc")));
    s.setTime(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("time")));
    s.setType(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type")));

    if(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("alarm")) == 1)
        s.setAlarm(true);
    else
        s.setAlarm(false);
    Log.d("dbcheck", s.toString());
    sched_list.add(s);
    c.moveToNext();
}
dbHelper.close();
Log.d("dbcheck", "==============================");
for(Schedule sc: sched_list)
{
    Log.d("dbcheck", sc.toString());
}
ScheduleAdapter schedListAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(this, R.layout.schedule_list_item, sched_list);
event_list.setAdapter(schedListAdapter);

event_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    TextView sched_id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sched_id);

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ScheduleActivity.this, sched_id.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

}
});
```

So my problem is when i click an item on the ListView which is inside a Dialog box, it does nothing, i can't click or it isn't clickable nothing happens as the picture states

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making items of the view **R.layout.schedule_list_item** not clickable and not focusable.

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

If any child view of **R.layout.schedule_list_item** can gain focus, then **OnItemClickListener()** may not work properly.

Comment: yes yes i added some button in schedule_list_item one for alarm and one for delete.. so i shou;d make the layout of schedule_list_item to clickable and focusable to false? is that wat ur saying?

Comment: not the entire schedule_list_item layout, just make the focusable property to false for the buttons in that view (only if you dont want to process the onClick event of that buttons)

Comment: but i have to set the buttons inside the list clickable... for delete specially

Comment: yep tried removing the button in the list item.. each item now is clickable.. but how do i add buttons in the list without compromising the clickability of the item. i need to add buttons to add delete function and stuff

Comment: you can add onClick listeners for those buttons in ScheduleAdapter class.

Answer (score 0):

> Uou should enter this code into   event_list.setOnItemClickListener

I think it will solve your problem

> `((ScheduleAdapter)event_list.getAdapter()).getItem(0);`

Comment: i don't understand what you mean? can u please elaborate?

Comment: its not neccessary to sync with getitem(0)..when perform another operation like dele..etc this will help u....